# Possible to un-anonymize VALUES clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have the following as a starting point:

```
select * from (values (1,'a'),(2,'b'))
```

Is it possible to provide column names to the value columns up-stream, for example something like:

```
select
    col1 AS id,
    col2 AS letter
from (
    <anonymous values>
)
```

Or is it basically once you have an anonymous `values` clause you cannot name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [table alias](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES) that also specifies column names:

```
select * 
from ( 
  values (1,'a'),(2,'b')
) as v(id, letter);
```

Comment: How do you specify the exact data-type of each column?

Comment: @Dai: the type is inferred from the actual values you provided in the `values` clause. If you need to force a specific type, use a `cast`

Answer (score 1):

use an alias:

```sql
select * from (values (1,'a'),(2,'b')) as foo(id,txt);
 id | txt
----+-----
  1 | a
  2 | b
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely

Just add the column names to the query alias

```
select q.id, q.col
from (values 
 (1,'a'),
 (2,'b')
) q(id, col)
```